# Converting VB to C# (Arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

I'm not very familiar with VB.net at the moment and having some trouble converting the following code to C#.

```
Dim itemList As New ArrayList
Dim strMyitemList(itemList.Count - 1) As String

        For x = 0 To (itemList.Count - 1)
            strMyitemList(x) = itemList(x)
        Next
```

So far I've got:

```
ArrayList itemList = new ArrayList();
string[] strMyitemList = new string[itemList.Count -1];

            for (int x = 0; x <= (itemList.Count - 1); x++)
            {
                strMyitemList[x] = itemList(x);
            }
```

I'm getting the error CS0149 "Method name expected" on "itemList(x)".

Thanks

Comment: Dont use `ArrayList` anymore, there is no reason

Comment: If you're not familiar with vb.net, what prevents you from writing working C# code?

Comment: @user202729 I am required to convert something that already exists to C# from VB.net. However, was trying to understand the VB to convert it.

Comment: change strMyitemList[x] = itemList(x); to strMyitemList[x] = itemList[x];

Comment: In C# you shouldn't use `itemList.Count - 1` when declaring the array. It is only used in VB.NET because it handles arrays differently.

Comment: In C#, you specify the array size using length, not upper bound, so your array declaration should look like: string[] strMyitemList = new string[itemList.Count];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itemList` is an `ArrayList` which has an indexer. In C# you use them with `[]`:

```
strMyitemList[x] = (string)itemList[x];
```

But nowadays there is no reason to use `ArrayList`. Use a strongly typed `List<string>`:

```
strMyitemList[x] = itemList[x];
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I noticed I'd added the square brackets to strMyitemList but  not itemList (also forgot the cast).